# Passing an array of objects from one function to another as an argument

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object

I am trying to pass an array of objects from one function to another.

The initial function returns an array of objects like this:

```
0
: 
{id: 661447, title: 'Square Deviled Eggs', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661447-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
1
: 
{id: 638035, title: 'Chicken Cordon Bleu', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/638035-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
2
: 
{id: 641896, title: 'Easy Chicken Cordon Bleu', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/641896-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
3
: 
{id: 652359, title: 'Monte Carlo Sandwich', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/652359-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
4
: 
{id: 663641, title: 'Tomato tarte tatin', image: 'https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/663641-312x231.jpg', imageType: 'jpg', usedIngredientCount: 2, …}
```

I then take that array and add the title of each recipe into the dom wrapped in <h2> and <a> tags, (data is the array of recipes):

```
let recipeTitles = function(){
                return data.map(el => `<a onClick="showRecipe(${el.id}, ${data})" href="#" class="recipeTitles" id="${el.id}"><h2 >${el.title}</h2></a>`).join('')
            }
            
document.querySelector('#recipeTitle').innerHTML = recipeTitles()
```

As you can see there the <a> tags contain

```
onClick="showRecipe(${el.id}, ${data})"
```

which is the next function, and I am trying to pass the items id (which works) and the entire array of objects.

For now showRecipe is very simple because I am just trying to get it to work:

```
function showRecipe(id, data) {
    console.log(data)
    console.log(data.title)
}
```

but when I click on one of the anchor tags that trigger showRecipe on the page I get a syntax error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'Object' (at index.html:1:28)
```

And if I click in I see

```
showRecipe(661447, [object Object])
```

so something is going wrong with the way I am trying to input 'data' as an argument I think.

I've tried multiple different variations

I thought

```
onClick="showRecipe(${el.id}, ${[...data]})"
```

might help

I thought

```
onClick="showRecipe(${el.id}, ${data[i]})"
```

Could possibly work, but there is something I am not understanding here.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using inline JS in 2022. Use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/). Add one click listener to the `recipeTitle` container, and have that catch and process events from its child elements as they bubble up the DOM (you may need to use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to capture some data). You can then remove the `onclick` attributes from that code.

Comment: Why are you passing the whole array to `showRecipe()`? Just pass the recipe ID, and let the function search the global variable for that ID.

Comment: Actually just using the recipe ID was what I was initially doing, but 'data' is not a global variable. It is from an API call within this function. 

And because it was from within the function it ceased to exist once the function was ran, so when showRecipe() was trying to check 'data' for the relevant id, there was no data to check.

So i thought maybe if I pass data straight into showRecipe as an argument I wouldn't face that problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. As I mentioned in comments you should use [event delegation](https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-event-delegation/) to handle the events from your recipe links. Add one listener to the containing element and have that deal with any click events that bubble up from its child elements. No more inline JS. Just add a [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to each item which the event handler can use.
2. As Barmar mentioned there's no need to pass around the whole dataset. When you click on a link (I've used list items in my example) you can use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the appropriate object from the array based on its id.

```js
const data=[{id:661447,title:"Square Deviled Eggs",image:"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661447-312x231.jpg",imageType:"jpg",usedIngredientCount:2},{id:638035,title:"Chicken Cordon Bleu",image:"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/638035-312x231.jpg",imageType:"jpg",usedIngredientCount:2}];

// Cache the container, and add a listener to it
const recipes = document.querySelector('#recipes');
recipes.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

// When the container detects an event from one of
// its children calls this function which checks to see
// if the element was a list item, grabs its id from its
// dataset, and then finds the corresponding object in the
// data array
function handleClick(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('li')) {
    const { id } = e.target.dataset;
    const recipe = data.find(recipe => recipe.id === +id);
    console.log(recipe);
  }
}

// Return an HTML string - note the
// id data attribute which is used in the click
// handler
function createListItems(data) {
  return data.map(recipe => {
    return `
      <li data-id="${recipe.id}">
        ${recipe.title}
      </li>`;
  }).join('');
}

recipes.innerHTML = `<ul>${createListItems(data)}</ul>`;
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin-left: 0px; }
li { padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #efefef; }
```

```html
<section id="recipes"></section>
```

An alternative might be to use a class to encapsulate the methods, and the data in one place.

```js
function mockFetch() {

  const data=[{id:661447,title:"Square Deviled Eggs",image:"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/661447-312x231.jpg",imageType:"jpg",usedIngredientCount:2},{id:638035,title:"Chicken Cordon Bleu",image:"https://spoonacular.com/recipeImages/638035-312x231.jpg",imageType:"jpg",usedIngredientCount:2}];

  return new Promise(res => {
    setTimeout(() => res(JSON.stringify(data)), 1000);
  });
}


class Recipes {

  // Pass in the root element, and set a listener on it
  constructor(root) {
    this.root = root;
    this.root.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick.bind(this));
  }

  // The same handleClick method as before
  handleClick(e) {
    if (e.target.matches('li')) {
      const { id } = e.target.dataset;
      const recipe = this.recipes.find(recipe => recipe.id === +id);
      console.log(recipe);
    }
  }

  // Fetch the data
  init() {
    this.fetchData();
  }

  // Using our mock API we can get the data and
  // assign it to `this.recipes` which can be accessed
  // by all the methods. Notes you'd probably want to do
  // `this.recipes = await res.json()` with a proper API
  async fetchData() {
    const res = await mockFetch();
    this.recipes = JSON.parse(res);
    this.appendRecipes();
  }
  
  // Create the items as before, and add them to the
  // root element
  appendRecipes() {
    const items = this.createListItems();
    this.root.innerHTML = `<ul>${items}</ul>`;
  }

  // Same as before just using `this.recipes` rather
  // than `data`
  createListItems() {
    return this.recipes.map(recipe => {
      return `
        <li data-id="${recipe.id}">
          ${recipe.title}
        </li>`;
    }).join('');
  }

}

// Initialise the root element, instantiate a new recipe object
// from the Recipe class (passing in the root element), and then
// call init (which fetches the data)
const root = document.querySelector('#recipes');
const recipes = new Recipes(root);
recipes.init();
```

```css
ul { list-style: none; padding: 0px; margin-left: 0px; }
li { padding: 0.2em; border: 1px solid #dfdfdf; }
li:hover { cursor: pointer; background-color: #efefef; }
```

```html
<section id="recipes"></section>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to write this. I think I didn't explain it well enough initially, but data is not a global variable. It is returned from an API call and parsed in the initial function. So when the initial function stops running it ceases to exist. This is why i was trying to pass it to the second function in the hopes that it would prevent this problem.

Comment: I only wrote it like this to ensure that the previous/next properties of the last fetched data could be used. Are you ruling a global variable out? @acodeaday

Comment: Well, I am not necessarily against it, but I was always under the impression that it's best to avoid global variables where possible in order to keep your code clean? I'm a bit of a noob, so I'm learning

Comment: I am also having trouble getting  event delegation to work, when I click the anchor text, nothing happens in the console. I tried to recreate it in codepen https://codepen.io/acodeaday/pen/QWrYpBp

Comment: Let me have a think @acodeaday.

Comment: @acodeaday I've added an alternative solution using a class which allows you to encapsulate the methods and data all in one place. It might be useful.